# Is a Vice President term limited in the same way the President is?

Tags: united-states, president, presidential-term

In other words can a vice-president serve as vice-president for 3 or more terms?

Just wondering if Joe Biden could be Hillary Clinton's running mate

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Vice-President is not term limited as Vice-president. The term limitation comes from the 22nd Amendment, which says nothing of the Vice-President. It reads, in whole:

> AMENDMENT XXII
>
> Section 1.
> No person shall be elected to the office of the President more than twice, and no person who has held the office of President, or acted as President, for more than two years of a term to which some other person was elected President shall be elected to the office of the President more than once. But this Article shall not apply to any person holding the office of President when this Article was proposed by the Congress, and shall not prevent any person who may be holding the office of President, or acting as President, during the term within which this Article becomes operative from holding the office of President or acting as President during the remainder of such term.
>
> Section 2.
> This article shall be inoperative unless it shall have been ratified as an amendment to the Constitution by the legislatures of three-fourths of the several States within seven years from the date of its submission to the States by the Congress.

This opens the interesting possibility that you could have someone as vice-president continuously over time. Obviously, that has never happened.

Comment: Just based on this, it sounds like if you had already been president for two full terms you could still run as vice president, and then if something happened to the President you'd be back in! It just says you can't be _elected_ as president again. Quite a loophole.

Comment: @Matt, twelfth amendment: "But no person constitutionally ineligible to the office of President shall be eligible to that of Vice-President of the United States."

Comment: @Matt It sounds like a president with a previously serving, now vice president, could be quite prone to 'falling down stairs'. If I was president I would think twice about having them as my vice president.

Comment: There's no limit to how many years someone could serve as acting President if one were elected VP, took over for an incapacitated President, ran again as VP and was elected that office, again assumed the role of acting preisdent, etc. without ever being elected President.

Comment: @supercat well, you would look very suspicious after a while.

Comment: @tox123: The likelihood of such a thing happening is essentially zero, but it would nonetheless be a legitimate scenario by which someone could serve an arbitrary number of years as acting President.

Comment: We refer you again to the 12th amendment:  "But no person constitutionally ineligible to the office of President shall be eligible to that of Vice-President of the United States."  Once people have been President for six or more years, they are no longer eligible to be Vice-President.  So they could no longer get elected as Vice-President.  Nor assume the office of President through the line of succession.  One could argue that the 22nd amendment only bars election, but in concert with the 12th, the most sensible reading is that it bars elevation in general.

Comment: If the president and Vice President die, someone who had been president before twice  could become president though right?

Comment: @Brythan,  Just because someone is not allowed to be "**elected** to the office of the President" why does it make them "**ineligible** to the office of President"?

Comment: +Brythan @IanRingrose Very interesting, thanks! The last paragraph of the Wikipedia subsection on the EC and the 12th Amdmt has a pretty good summary, indicating that this is an ongoing debate. Quoting the start: "While it is clear that under the Twelfth Amendment the original constitutional qualifications of age, citizenship, and residency apply to both the President and Vice President, it is unclear whether a two-term president could later serve as Vice President."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelfth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution#Electoral_College_under_the_Twelfth_Amendment

Comment: @IanRingrose  That's also a possible reading, but it conflicts with the section of the 22nd that says, "shall not prevent any person who may be holding the office of President, or acting as President, during the term within which this Article becomes operative from holding the office of President or acting as President during the remainder of such term."  If this did not impact eligibility to be President, then that clause is unnecessary.  The legal assumption is that that section is necessary, so the 22nd must control eligibility.

Comment: @Lembik  No.  People who are ineligible to be President are not in the line of succession even if they hold an office that should be.  For example, Secretary of State Madeleine Albright was not in the line of succession because she was not a natural born citizen.

Comment: @Brythan What part of the constitution says someone who has served two terms is ineligible to be president? Doesn't it just refer to being *elected* president?

Comment: No, see my previous comment (before the one directed to you).  The implication of the exception clauses is that they are necessary, and the second exception clause addresses the possibility that someone might be President or Acting President at that time.  If it only impacted elections, then that exception is superfluous.  A President would have already been elected and an Acting President is not elected.  Legally, it is a more natural reading that the exception is necessary and that no one who has six or more years as President can assume the office in any way except resuming after disability